# Magento does not upgrade

Tags: magento, upgrade

I've got some questions about upgrading Magento (running 1.7.0.0)

I've got root-access over the command line, but the upgrade-all function does nothing for a long time.

The current commands were executed, but nothing happens, any idea?

```
[root@httpdocs]# ./mage mage-setup
Running initial setup...
Success
Success
Error:
channel-add: Channel 'community' already exist!
[root@httpdocs]# ./mage sync
[root@httpdocs]# ./mage upgrade-all --force
```

It does know there are updates:

```
[root@httpdocs]# ./mage list-upgrades
Updates for community:
  Mage_All_Latest: 1.7.0.0 => 1.7.0.2
  Interface_Adminhtml_Default: 1.7.0.0 => 1.7.0.1
  Mage_Downloader: 1.7.0.0 => 1.7.0.1
  Interface_Frontend_Base_Default: 1.7.0.0 => 1.7.0.1
  Magento_Mobile: 1.7.0.0.22.1 => 1.7.0.1.22.1
  Mage_Core_Adminhtml: 1.7.0.0 => 1.7.0.1
  Mage_Core_Modules: 1.7.0.0 => 1.7.0.2
  Lib_Mage: 1.7.0.0 => 1.7.0.1
```

The following code did do some installations, but I don't know why it did not upgrade to 1.7.0.2:

```
[root@httpdocs]# ./mage install connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have not used MagentoConnect or PEAR command line to install Magento, you will need to enter this command for initial PEAR installation of all Magento core modules:

```
./pear install magento-core/Mage_All_Latest
```

Comment: Well, here's the thing: I don't have the ./pear file. When I download the latest Magento, 1.7.0.2, the file is neither included in the archive. Any explanation for that?

Comment: replace ./pear with ./mage (I think they change it recently)

Comment: Isn't that what I did in my initial post? I believe I ran all the necessary commands, but nothing seems to change.

Comment: Try to upgrade using this method.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163847/magento-upgrade-takes-too-long-and-never-completes